# Do people find someone in a list faster by name or a profile picture of the person?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, image, lists, speed

I am looking for research to find out if when looking through a list such as a team list in a project management app people find it easier to find someone by their profile picture or their name?
I am designed an app which has a team list and so I am trying to decide whether a profile picture would help in this scenario or not.

Comment: If you were to rely on the profile picture it might not be effective unless you required pictures to be realistic.  Many people like to use a logo or symbol or a personalized interpretive picture instead of a "passport photo" type picture as their avatar.

Comment: I would go with both. Seeing a picture by itself is unreliable. However, a list of similar sounding names that you are unfamiliar with is also not helpful.

Comment: This is also gender-specific. Please also remember that a lot of mugshots are of less than professional quality or not fit for a professional setting. Source: own experience with Trello... (sigh)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a significant body of work in the field of neuroscience which suggests that the human brain is highly adapted to the process of recognizing faces. In fact, the activity is so specialized, it's suspected that the brain has a region, the [fusiform face area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusiform_face_area), devoted solely to that task.

A classic work on the subject is [Face-Specific Processing in the Human Fusiform Gyrus](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/jocn.1997.9.5.605). The study looked at the activation of different regions of the brain when viewing faces vs non-faces and found that viewing faces triggered a different response in the Fusiform Gyrus, which led to the identification of the "fusiform face area". From the abstract:

> These results demonstrate that both faces and flowers activate large
>   and partially overlapping regions of inferior extrastriate cortex. A
>   smaller region, located primarily in the right lateral fusiform gyrus,
>   is activated specifically by faces.

Another, more recent study, [Face processing without awareness in the right fusiform gyrus](http://www.yale.edu/cnl/papers/Face%20Processing%20without%20awareness%20in%20the%20right%20fusiform%20gyrus%20%282007%29.pdf) suggests that face recognition can be an unconscious activity. In this study, the subjects' brains responded differently when exposed to faces vs. non-faces, even when the exposure was so brief that the subjects themselves could not determine if they'd been shown a face or non-face! Again, from the abstract:

> These data provide strong evidence for an automatic face-processing
>   region in the right FFG.

It's not clear from the research I've seen (although I am admittedly not that well read in neuroscience) that people recognize faces *faster* than they recognize names (ie., I don't know that someone has done this exact study), but given that names are a cultural construct and faces a biological one (with the aforementioned corresponding specialty brain hardware), I don't think it's a huge reach to assert such.

So that's the research, but from user experience perspective it's more salient to identify how users behave rather than how their minds work. And from this perspective, it's not clear that there's a choice to make here. We may find, for example, that irrespective of their brains' natural ability to recognize faces, some users prefer a text search. In this case, support text search. We may also find that some users prefer to scan rapidly through a list of faces. So support that. In fact, it seems evident that you can support both of these paradigms without negatively impacting either and so you *should* support both.

A final note: while text only may be appropriate (if, for example, you do not actually have pictures available), face only is never appropriate: [face blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopagnosia), impaired ability to recognize faces, affects up to 2.5% of the population.

Comment: Great links but can you provide a quick summary of those links ?

Comment: "In fact, the activity is so specialized, it's suspected that the brain has a special area devoted solely to that task, the fusiform face area." This is the summary. The study looked at the activation of different regions of the brain when viewing faces vs non-faces and found that viewing faces triggered a different response in the Fusiform Gyrus, which led to the identification of the "fusiform face area". The study is quite old now (1997) but I'm not read into the more recent research.

Comment: Not in the comments, in the question answer please :)

Comment: I'm confused. I did summarize it in the answer. If you don't like the summary, please suggest an improvement.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very clear, when you add a summary its better to provide it within quotation marks so that it stands out. Please refer for some of my answers to see examples of how to give summaries

Comment: OK, fair suggestion. I made some changes. Let me know if you think I'm missing something.

Comment: @BenjaminMalley, it might be from 1997 but research takes time. I wouldn't be surprised if the research is still fairly accurate but then again, sometimes research changes very quickly.

Comment: Oh, I'm not questioning the accuracy of the research, merely signalling that there may be more recent research which more specifically addresses the question posed (ie., facial vs name recognition). In fact, I later added a paper from 2007 which talks about *automatic* processing.

Comment: While I am intrigued to learn this, I think it doesn't really help the objective as much: *finding* a person in a list. Unless faces can be sorted (the research you provide may eventually actually lead to that, who knows), there is simply no advantage to pictures in terms of search speed because of the "sortable" nature of names, correct?

Comment: Let's separate "finding" into "searching" (query->results) and "scanning" (iterating through the results). RE:scanning, providing faces may enable users to scan more quickly and to differentiate between people with similar names. Benefit achieved. RE:searching, images can be searched, provided the query is itself an image. This is less relevant as the question describes "looking through a list," ie., scanning. RE:sorting, adding images to list of names would not make said list unsortable, so I can't understand your point there. In summary, I don't think it's correct to say there's no benefit.

Comment: So to be clear, if the two components of scanning are 1) progressing through a list and 2) recognizing a match, a picture of someone's face has some potential benefit in component 2. That is, there's evidence I might recognize my buddy Jim faster from his picture than from his name. While I agree there may be no clear benefit to component 1, there is certainly no detriment.

Comment: +1 for mentioning face blindness, which I unfortunately suffer from (2.5%, represent!) That being said, face-only is probably inappropriate for *all* blindness, and I can't imagine it'll play well with a screen reader.

Answer (score 6):

**If at all possible, have a profile pictures and names together**.  Profile pictures and names serve fairly different purposes, but they are most useful when used together.

Lets say I know someone's name from emailing them, but not what they look like.  If there is a meeting, and I want to be able to recognise them, I need to see a face next to a name.

If I just had a meeting and met someone, but forgot their name (the bane of my life), then I want to see pictures that I can look through to find their name.

Comment: ah sorry +1, must have skipped your answer somehow while reading, though i suppose specifying a *sorted* list couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Using photos can help users personalize themselves and provide a visual representation in case someone is searching for them. Photos can also help in determining which John smith you want to email (assuming as Obelia right pointed out that both John smiths are using their own pictures and not some random logo and you know that they look for) and can serve as an additional visual aide of recognition (unless both people have the same name and look very alike or have similar profile pics).

However I recommend also showing the name along with the photo as that would be the easiest way to search for someone instead of trying to look across photos and determining who is who. Here are some examples of some iPhone apps which do it well:

[image][image]

Comment: A side note: it is pointless to have a photo with sunglasses on...

Comment: @Deer Hunter: What? Why? There's still lots of other visual cues in the photo - the hairstyle, shape of face, size of nose, etc. "Despite" their sunglasses, I can tell that Robert Vojta and Vu Hoang Anh both aren't people I know but Robert Vojta looks a bit like one of my uncles.